# Вернуть layout к разметке из xml. Перерисовать layout

Tags: android

Программно дополняю layout, нужно заново перерисовать layout. Удалять каждый объект не хочется. Есть ли какая-то возможность заново взять layout из xml файла?

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setinterface(); //тут программно добавляю
```

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); И все.

Comment: Спасибо, как все просто.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ из комментариев – [nekaneka](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14563/nekaneka) 9 июнь в 11:18

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```